# C++ Cast from ‘std::__tuple... {aka ‘unsigned int*’} to ‘uint32_t’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} loses precision

Tags: c++, pointers, precision, stdtuple, uint32

You may have to forgive me as I'm new to C++ and may have made some fundamental errors with the code I have worked up so far.

```
static tuple<read_result, uint8_t*> m_scan_record(bool skip, uint32_t& size, FILE* file)
{
    read_result result;
    
    tuple<read_result, uint32_t*> rd_rec_size_result = m_read_generic_t<uint32_t>(file);

    result = (read_result)get<0>(rd_rec_size_result);
    
    if (result != read_success )
    {
        return tuple<read_result, uint8_t*>(result, nullptr);
    }

    size = (uint32_t) get<1>(rd_rec_size_result);

    if ( skip )
    {
        fseek(file, size, SEEK_CUR);
    }
// ...
}

template<typename T>
static tuple<read_result, T*> m_read_generic_t(FILE* file)
{
    T ret = 0;
    
    read_result result = m_read_from_file_to_buffer(&ret, sizeof(T), file);

    if (result == read_success)
    {
        return tuple<read_result, T*>(result, &ret);
    }

    return tuple<read_result, T*>(result, nullptr);
}
```

When I compile this code I am getting this error:

```
cast from ‘std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<read_result, unsigned int*> >’ {aka ‘unsigned int*’} to ‘uint32_t’ {aka ‘unsigned int’} loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

My intentions and what I am expected to do/happen:

1. In the declaration of `m_scan_record`, the `size` argument is declared with a `&` which is intended to allow me to pass the value by reference, analogous to using the `REF` c# keyword
2. I make a call to generic (template) function `m_read_generic_t` which is called with the specified type `<unit32_t>` and therefore (according to its definition) will return a type of  `tuple<read_result, uint32_t*>`
3. Once I have the tuple returned by `m_read_generic_t`, I want to take the `unit32_t` value pointed to by the second value of the tuple, and put that value into the `size` variable mentioned at point 1, above, which presumably will then be accessible to the calling function one step further up the stack.
4. From the above points you can hopefully see that my intention (and I appreciate that I may be far away in reality!) is that at this line:

   size = (uint32_t) get<1>(rd_rec_size_result);

all I am doing is simply grabbing a 'pointed to' value and putting it into a variable of a matching type, much like the oft-cited textbook example:

```
uint32_t v = 123;
uint32_t* ptr_to_v = &v;
uint32_t x = ptr_to_v;   // x == 123
```

Clearly this is not what is really going on with my code, though, because if it were, I presume that the cast would be un-needed. But if I remove it, like this:

```
size = get<1>(rd_rec_size_result);
```

then I get a compile-time error:

```
a value of type "std::__tuple_element_t<1UL, std::tuple<read_result, uint32_t *>>" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "uint32_t"
```

I believe therefore that I am doing something badly wrong - but I can't work out what. Is this to do with the way I am taking the pointer out of the tuple; or is there something else going on when it comes to the getting a uint32_t value from a uint32_t* ?

This is all in a C++ environment on Ubuntu 20.04, FWIW

Many thanks in advance for any/all suggestions; please go easy on me!

Comment: You've left out at least the definition of `read_result` which seems central. Please make a [mcve]. You also have a few C type casts. Why are they needed? I don't see anything demanding the use of that type of casting anywhere. I don't see a reason for using `uint32_t` for the sizes either. Why not use the type returned by the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tuple<read_result, uint32_t*> rd_rec_size_result = ...
```

The 2nd member of this tuple, as explicitly declared here, is a pointer to a `uint32_t`. That's what `uint32_t *` means, in C++.

```
size = (uint32_t) get<1>(rd_rec_size_result);
```

This retrieves the `uint32_t *` and attempts to convert it to a `uint32_t`. C++ does not work this way. Although this conversion can be forced your compiler has every right to believe that whatever this code is trying to do it must be wrong.

Perhaps I was wondering initially, your intention was to dereference the pointer. This is the reason for your compilation error, in any case. If your intention was to, truly, dereference this pointer, then this would've been a simple matter of changing this to

```
size = *get<1>(rd_rec_size_result);
```

However, that's not going to be the end of your troubles. Even after this compilation error is fixed, this way, the shown code will still be badly, badly broken.

This is because `m_read_generic_t` returns a pointer to a local object, which will get destroyed when the function returns, and attempting to dereference this pointer, here, will make [demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

The *real* fix here is to change `m_read_generic_t` to ***not*** return a pointer as the 2nd value in the tuple in the first place, thus eliminating the compilation error in the first place.

Comment: I understand Sam - and this is simultaneously very enlightening so thank you. I shall go at the code again taking your observations in hand. I do not want demons coming out of my nose (or anybody else’s)!!  Thanks again.